# Camera stream (from getUserMedia) displayed in navigator but not in iframe

Tags: android, iframe, stream, android-camera, getusermedia

I have some problems to display the camera video stream of my emulator in an iframe.

**Aim:**
I am using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) to get the video stream from a device, display it on a webpage, and take a photo from the stream.

**Problem:**
When I open my webpage on a navigator I can see the camera video stream, take a photo and see the photo on the webpage. But when I open my webpage on a mobile application within an iframe, the video stream is not displayed (I only get a blank space). But even though I can't see the video stream, I still can take a photo from the stream and display the photo on my webpage. But I would like to see the stream before I take the photo.

**Tools:**
I am using **ionic2** for the mobile app displaying the webpage within an iframe.
I'm using an **emulator** (Pixel_XL_API_26) to open the webpage from the navigator (working) and from the mobile app (not working).
I'm using html and javascript to get the stream from my webpage.

**iframe code in the mobile app:**

```
<div id="iframeContainer" #frame style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll !important;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;">
    <iframe src="https://mypage" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**HTML code for the webpage:**

```
<div class="row">
    <video width="150" height="150" id="video" controls autoplay></video>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <button onclick="getStream()">Display video</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript code for the webpage:**

```
function getStream () {
    if (!navigator.getUserMedia && !navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
    && !navigator.mozGetUserMedia && !navigator.msGetUserMedia) {
        alert('User Media API not supported.');
        return;
    }

    var constraints = {video: true, audio: false};
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
        video = document.querySelector('video');

        if ('srcObject' in video) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);
        } 
        else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

I am quite stuck with this problem. As the webpage works perfectly on the emulator's navigator, I was wondering if maybe the iframe was blocking the stream somehow, but I have not been able to figure out why or how to get it to work.

Has anyone ever faced this problem? Does anyone know any solution or have any hints?

Thank you for your help ! :)
(Apologies if my English is not perfect)